# Create dynamic controls from JSON Response SAP UI5

Tags: json, checkbox, checkboxlist, sapui5

I have a requirement to create a group of checkbox with lebels in a page from JSON response.
The JSON response is

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "CodeStatus": "Red"
        },
        {
            "CodeStatus": "Orange"
        },
        {
            "CodeStatus": "Green"
        },
        {
            "CodeStatus": "Yellow"
        }
    ]
}
```

the  design is:

[image]

the box is vertically scrollable, as it can have more color codes.
Can anyone suggest how to design the above?
If one can provide the implemantation code, that would be very good as I have very time to implement it.

Comment: You're asking about a design, but you've already shown us that you've designed it. Then you ask for the code - is this because you haven't enough time? Are you asking us to write it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Create a JsonModel . use the setData() method to define its data from the json you got on the response.

Then use a VerticalLayout element and bind its content to "/data" on the model. 
This will create a "line" for each element on the data attribute of your model.
Use a template for the line that is a label+checkbox where the label text is bound to "CodeStatus".
You also need a checked attribute on each entry to store the checked attribute of the checkbox.